# How To Root a Switel Rock S4500D

Tags: rooting

I just got an Android phone, but the brand is not one of the famous or worldwide sold brands, it's a Switel Rock S4500D, and I want to root it. Can anyone help me how to do it?
As far as I googled, different ways and programs are based on phone brand and model.

Comment: As a "generic advice": Check our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) if the device is already listed and, if not, check the rooting methods below the devices list whether one matches. Still unsolved, then ask here – and include what you've checked and tried.

Comment: @Hitman2847 Did you ever succeed? I never found any information about rooting Switel phones. Either they are too hard to crack or (more likely) nobody cares about this brand.

Comment: @Daniel Alder : i didn't find anything and did not even try , it is a brand exclusive to switzerland manufactured by china so it is not even a brand :D and i find it unworthy of the money paid to purchase it , so i am planning to change it to a CATERPILLAR S50 soon . i only wanted to root this switel  because  it has a very small amount of storage

Answer (score 0):

I rooted many unknown brands in last two months and thr are couple of PC programs which will help you to do it easily.

1. [Kingoapp Root](http://www.kingoapp.com/)
2. [SRSRoot One Click Root for Android (SuperUser)](http://www.srsroot.com/)
3. Mobiegenie (I never tried this one)

all these programs require a windows PC and a Good Data cord for the process.

Comment: Vinay, it would be helpful to include links. While [Kingoapp Root](http://www.kingoapp.com/) is already mentioned in our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575), the other two are not – would add them if I had a link :)

Comment: Just found and added the links to Kingo & SRS. Are you sure Mobiegenie is a rooting app? I've just found a Windows software to manage your device by that name.

Comment: @Izzy mobogenie is a mobile device manager , but it also gives you the option to backup and restore files and settings as well as rooting your device , never tried rooting by mobogenie though